# prime number test in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`. I want to test which of the numbers are **prime** and wanted to produce the output `{1=>false, 2=>true, 3=>true, 4=>false, 5=>true}`.

Any one liner will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of prime numbers using Array methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592407/list-of-prime-numbers-using-array-methods)

Comment: What have you written? We need to see what code you've tried, so we can correct it.

Comment: Benchmark results for the answers are available at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6243956

Answer (score 7):

I posted this as a comment.

```
require 'prime'

a = (1..5).to_a
Hash[a.map{ |x| [x, x.prime?] }]
=> {1=>false, 2=>true, 3=>true, 4=>false, 5=>true}
```

Comment: +1. In benchmarks, with `a=(0..9).to_a` and `N=10_000` iterations I see 0.310000 sec. At `a=(0..99).to_a` and the same N it's up to 3.840000 sec. Benchmark code is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6243956

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks a lot for those benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

The below will work for you,using [**`Prime#prime?`**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F):

```
require 'prime'

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
Hash[a.zip(a.map(&Prime.method(:prime?)))]
# => {1=>false, 2=>true, 3=>true, 4=>false, 5=>true}
```

Comment: You could also do : `Hash[a.map{ |x| [x, x.prime?] }]`

Comment: +1 @bsd, that is nicely concise and should be an answer. @Babai, your attempt is convoluted; Why use `zip` when it'd all fit nicely in `map`?

Comment: @theTinMan in side map you create `[]` for each iteration,which I have created in one shot using `#zip`... I don't see any difference between me and @bsd code..

Comment: With `a=(0..9).to_a` and `N=10_000` iterations I see 0.330000 sec. At `a=(0..99).to_a` and the same N it's up to 4.000000 sec. Benchmark code is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6243956

Comment: @theTinMan I did test that.. but such point free style I like,thus i used it... thanks for your feedback..

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = {}

a.each {|i| results[i] = (1..i).map{|x| i/x.to_f % 1 == 0}.count(true) == 2}
puts results.inspect #=> {1 => false, 2 => true, 3 => true, 4 => false, 5 => true}
```

Comment: This is O(n**2). Ruby libraries uses sieve of eratosthenes which is very close to O(n)(it is actually around O(n lg lg n)).

Comment: That's really good to know, thanks!  I'll have to look into the Sieve of Eratosthenes :)

Comment: For very short arrays this is fast. It slows down drastically when the array size grows. With `a=(0..9).to_a` and `N=10_000` iterations I see 0.230000 sec. At `a=(0..99).to_a` and the same N it's up to 15.870000 sec.

Comment: Benchmark code is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6243956

Comment: Thanks for those results!  Makes it clear that my proposal is rather inefficient for larger values of n.  The Sieve of Eratosthenes is really interesting, and since it is already in 'prime', there's no real need for me to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There's often cases where using code like yours is faster for small sets. The benchmarks really help us understand that fact, so we can make an intelligent decision which way to go.